# "Vector Iterators incompatible" when deleting in a self contained vector loop

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

may I ask help to confirm if my issue comes from a Design problem or if there would be a possible clean solution to the following:

Entity.h

```
class CLEntity3D
{
public:
    CLEntity3D();
    virtual ~CLEntity3D();
    virtual void update() = 0;

    static std::vector<CLEntity3D*> vecEntity;  
};
```

Entity.cpp

```
int CLEntity3D::nbrEntity = 0;
std::vector<CLEntity3D*> CLEntity3D::vecEntity;

CLEntity3D::CLEntity3D()
{
    vecEntity.push_back(this);
}
CLEntity3D::~CLEntity3D()
{
    vecEntity.erase((std::remove(vecEntity.begin(), vecEntity.end(), this)), vecEntity.end());     
}
```

Various derived class are creating/deleting different Entities object through the program, this all works fine.

In a Scene class, I have the following methods:

```
void CLScene::Update()  
{
    for (auto& iter : CLEntity3D::vecEntity) {
        iter->update();
    }
}

void CLScene::ClearScene()
{
    for (auto& iter : CLEntity3D::vecEntity) {
        delete(iter); iter = nullptr;
    }
    CLEntity3D::vecEntity.clear();
}
```

Update is ok, the issue is with ClearScene().  I get a "Vector Iterators incompatible"  debug assertion.

From my research, the common problem seems to be because the iterators are from different vectors, which I don't think is the issue here. I think the problem is when ClearScene() is called, every delete(iter) changes the size of vecEntity through the CLEntity3D destructor therefore invalidates the iterator in the ClearScene loop. Am I right?

My question would then be:
Is there a way to delete all CLEntity3D objects from CLScene with that design?

I guess I could have CLScene holding the vecEntity, which would eliminate the problem but this would mean that CLScene would have to manage all creation/deletion of entities, therefore not being as versatile...

PS: I know this example is not one to compile but since my question is more about concept...  please advise if I shall provide otherwise.

Comment: The problem is that in `CLEntity3D`, you add `this` to the `vecEntity` vector, but the `CLEntity3D` instance may or may not have been constructed dynamically (e.g. `CLEntity3D entity;` vs. `CLEntity3D *entity = new CLEntity3D();`). If no dynamic allocation was performed, you cannot use `delete`.

Comment: i guess you wanted to write `*iter = nullptr;` instead of  `iter = nullptr;` if you change the iterator how it supposed to go to next?

Comment: @SHR This is a `for-range` loop, the `iter` variable is actually the pointer itself, not the iterator.

Comment: @SHR That's not an iterator there, he's using the range-based for loop.

Comment: There is a strong case for having each `CLScene` manage it's own private entity list rather than it being a static member of and managed by `CLEntity3D`. For one thing it opens the code up to the possibility of multiple scenes. For another  `vecEntity` is public. Anyone can delete any entities at any time, leaving `CLScene` in a very dangerous position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you can't remove anything from the underlying vector while inside a range based for loop.

The loop in your `ClearScene` method deletes `CLEntity3D` instances, which in it's destructor changes the same vector you used in your for loop.

A relatively easy fix would be to change your `ClearScene` to something like this:

```
void CLScene::ClearScene()
{
    auto vectorCopy = CLEntity3D::vecEntity;
    for (auto& iter : vectorCopy) {
        delete iter;
    }
}
```

This works because the loop operates on a copy, and the remove happens on the original.

Note that there is no need to clear the original vector after the loop, since the destructors ensure that the vector will be empty after deleting every item.

Or as suggested by a comment, you could avoid the copy by using a while loop:

```
while (!CLEntity3D::vecEntity.empty()) 
{
   delete CLEntity3D::vecEntity.begin();
}
```

Comment: Check the `CLEntity3D` destructor, it removes the current item from the vector.

Comment: Ah, I missed that. I think the code is too broken to fix.

Comment: Save yourself the copy: `while (! CLEntity3D::vecEntity.empty()) delete CLEntity3D::vecEntity.begin();`

Comment: That depends on the definition of a fix. Copying the vector clearly solves the iterator assert, but there is definitely a bigger design problem here.